# URL Validation in PHP

Tags: php, validation, url

The topic has been discussed a lot here at StackOverflow but all the answers I managed to explore fail to produce the results I need. I want to check before inserting the URL into database that the value is actually a URL. The default function of PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_URL returns true even if we just provide httpp://exampl

but I need to validate the value only if it is a true domain like example.net, example.com etc.. Let's try an example:

Case 1:

```
$url = "http://example";
if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
                return true;
            }
```

This above returns true but domain isn't valid.

Case 2:

```
$url = "http://google.com";
if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
                return true;
            }
```

Returns true and that's okay.

But any possible solution for case 1? Please help.

P.S.: I used CURL and it works but the response is too slow (more than 5 seconds). Any solid solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is a *true domain*? im not sure what you consider to be valid

Comment: Will [get_headers](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) help ?

Comment: Thanks @Dagon, for your response. Sorry for my typos in the question. I have edited it. I mean http://example cannot be a valid domain as it lacks TLD (.com, .net etc) but the function considers it as a valid domain. I hope I made you clear about my question.

Comment: do you mean true as "well formed" like `http://www.still-might-not-exist.com` or truely true like there is intelligent life in `http://example` (yes... you could have a server in the lan answering to this?

If you want to check the server is there you have no options but to probe them...

Then the answer speed is not in your hands

Comment: @SearchAndResQ: Thanks for the idea. You mean should I look for the response sent by the target server to consider the domain as an active one? If you meant this, I'll consider if I fail to find any other solution.

Comment: can't you prepare regex for that?

Comment: @rehmat  `^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.[^\W]+.com)(\/[^\W]+)+  ` this might help to you.

Comment: What's the difference between case 1 and case 2 ?

Comment: You could use a regex as a first check. To discard things you are obviously not interested in like your `http://example` But if you need to know if the server is alive (at that moment) you got to test it somehow. Then... curl, get_headers, gile_get_contents... whatever you try the bottleneck will never be your code but the remote server and the net.
You just can't rush them...

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` because it also accepts `mailto:`  `ssh:` etc. I would use a regular expressions to validate your URL.

Comment: @JulioSoares: Thanks, get_headers may be a solution for me.

Comment: @PedroLobito Exactly, it isn't reliable in most cases.

Comment: Do you need to validate ftp also ? or just http ?

Comment: Will you check if the url is valid using curl ? your question isn't clear on this point.

Comment: I want to validate only http.. curl takes long to to respond. If you have a good solution even using curl, please share

Comment: @rehmat curl will take less time to execute if you don't request the body (`CURLOPT_NOBODY`), check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've coded a quick script that may help you achieving what you need :

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$url = "http://www.google.com";


if(validateUrl($url)){
    echo "VALID";
}else{
    echo "INVALID";
}

function validateUrl($url){

//first we validate the url using a regex

if (!preg_match('%^(?:(?:https?)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]-*)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]-*)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$%uiS', $url)) {

    return false;
}


//if the url is valid, we "curl it" and expect to get a 200 header response in order to validate it.

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body (faster)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); // we follow redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);


if($httpcode == "200"){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks, without fetching the body, the response is faster. I'll stick to this unless I find something faster than this one :)

Answer (score 1):

http://example is a valid url - if you have a computer called example on your local network.

The only solution for what you want (especially considering that there are lots of new top level domains) is to connect and see if you get 200 OK.

CURL is probably the best solution here.

This [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code) question might help to just get the response code from a url.

However you will never get 100% accuracy